# Something rewrites rules for php when Apache mod_rewrite module is disabled

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I run the following url:

```
http://localsite/index.php/foo/bar
```

index.php is executed and outputs variable:

```
$_SERVER[SCRIPT_FILENAME] = E:/path/to/file/index.php
```

mod_rewrite in Apache is disabled.

**Who rewrites the rule?**
Or what happens?

How index.php is found? Why apache decided to run it?

My configuration:
Windows Vista, Apache Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) PHP/5.3.1 (with php module).

(Indeed the problem is the rule is actually rewritten before mod_rewrite - this is when mod_rewrite is enabled. This causes that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is always false, because `/foo/bar` is trimmed before `RewriteCond`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) Apache directive.

It treats everything up to

```
http://localsite/index.php
```

as the resource, and puts

```
/foo/bar
```

into the `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]` variable.

It's sometimes used as a poor man's URL rewriter when `mod_rewrite` isn't available - with the downside that in a normal configuration, there has to be a `.php` somewhere in the URL.

Your options are to turn this off, or to use a different URL - depending on your situation.

Comment: It was really difficult for me to realize that something else is rewriting urls also. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a rewrite - you had an incorrect understanding of how URLs are parsed. For more info, see Section 3.2 in http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875.txt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] instead, afaik, SCRIPT_FILENAME tells you which file php was started with.